# Вероятностнй анализ алгоритма с двумя переменными

Tags: алгоритм, теория-вероятностей

Столкнулся с проблемой при вероятностном анализе алгоритма, а именно с индикаторной функцией. Но, начну сначала: есть массив чисел A, все числа в нём разные и заданы случайно (интервал чисел неизвестен). Нужно написать алгоритм на псевдокоде, который будет возвращать все пары чисел A[i]+A[j] mod 2 = 0, при условии, что i<j. C алгоритмом у меня проблем не возникло, т.к. нет никаких ограничений на его эффективность, сделал такой вариант:

```
procedureDisjunktePaare(Array)%(Input - Array, Output - Array of Paars) 
Result = ([])
for i = 1 to Array.size-1 do
   while j=i+1 to Array.size do
       if Array.i+Array.j mod 2 == 0 then 
            append(Result, (Array.i, Array.j))
       j++  
   i=i++
return Result
```

Алгоритм простой как валенок: i начинается с первого элемента массива, заканчивается на предпоследнем. j начинается с i+1, заканчивается последним элементом. Во вложенном цикле проверяем условие и если оно выполняется - просто добавляем пару в список Result. Когда цикл For проходит полностью - возвращаем результат.

Очевидно, что в самом худшем случае у нас будет (n-1)(n-1) операций (в случае если все элементы в массиве отсортированы по возрастающей и все они удовлетворяют условию для попадания в список. В данном случае мы делаем n-1 итераций в цикле for, а в цикле While мы делаем в первый раз n-1 поторений, затем n-2 итд вплоть до одной единственной итерации для последней итерации цила for). Но вероятность такого исхода не очень велика. Поэтому для ожидаемого времени надо применить вероятностный анализ. С этим чуть сложнее.

Я понимаю, что надо использовать как советует Кормен индикаторную функцию. Но я не очень понимаю, как задать её для условия, что одна переменная будет меньше другой.
Но каково тогда E[Xi]?  Насколько я понимаю, я должен отталкиваться от следующего:
Xi=1, если A[i]+A[j] mod 2 = 0; 0 - во всех остальных случаях.
Для этого либо оба элемента должны быть чётные, либо оба элемента должны быть нечётные. Т.к. у нас предполагается полный рандом, то вероятность любого из этих событий 1/4, что делает суммарную вероятность 0.5. Но мне кажется, что такой подход абсолютно наивен и ошибочен.

Comment: Эээ... Какой может быть вероятностный анализ, если задача в том, чтобы **вернуть все пары**?`Ожидаемое время` - время чего?

Comment: @MBo, ожидаемое время работы алгоритма, т.к. работа его зависит от наполнения массива, а сам массив наполняется рандомно. ВСЕ пары будут возвращаться лишь в худшем случае, в остальных же случаях будет лишь часть пар попадать под условия A[i]+A[j] mod 2 = 0, i<J.

Comment: Но проверяться будут все пары, поэтому алгоритм выполняет порядка n^2/2 операций

Comment: Да, проверяются все пары, но Append выполняется только для подходящих под условие.

Comment: При любом раскладе данный алгоритм квадратичный. Видимо, я не понял смысл задачи, так что больше приставать не буду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного посидев и подумав, я нашёл то, что искал. Искомое решение было следующим:
Пусть индикаторная переменная Х будет следующей:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тогда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я уже писал в вопросе, наше условие работает когда оба сверяемых числа чётные или оба нечётные. Вероятность каждого из этих событий 1/4. Вероятность, что выпадет одно из этих событий - 1/2. В этом случае
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моей ошибкой было то, что я забыл, что в случае ряда, если у нас константа под знаком, то мы всё равно можем применить формулу (см последнее изображение).

Answer (score 3):

Вообще ваш алгоритм при любых входных данных сделает `~n^2/2` сравнений (`1+2+ ... +(n - 1)`). Но кажется вы спрашиваете, какая средняя величина результирующего массива в конце алгоритма.

Пусть `F(n, k)` - количество пар в результирующем массиве, если во входных данных `k` четных чисел и `n - k` нечетных чисел. Очевидно, что `F(x) = k * (k - 1) / 2 + (n - k) * (n - k - 1) / 2`. Тогда мат. ожидание размера результирующего массива будет выражаться следующей функцией:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если вы верите вольфраму, то результат будет следующим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это, конечно, не вероятностный анализ, но как мне кажется, мой способ даже проще и точнее.